# Aws Glue generates Random output file name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am using AWS Glue to transform some XML files into JSON files. I have added the files to Glue table from S3.
The job I have set up reads the files from the source bucket, the job runs successfully, and there are files added to the correct S3 bucket. The issue I have is that it **generates a random name**. And **one extra file is added with 0kb**.

Here is my script:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a GlueContext and SparkSession
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

source_bucket = "xml_data_search"
target_bucket = "athena-xml-to-json-results"

# Read the XML files from the source S3 bucket
datasource = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "default", table_name = source_bucket)

# Convert the XML files to a DataFrame
source_df = datasource.toDF()

output_file = "output"

# Write the DataFrame as a JSON file to the target S3 bucket
source_df.write.mode("overwrite").json(f"s3://{target_bucket}/{output_file}")
```

Here is my source folder. I have 3 files in source.
[image]

Here is my output folder, **It generates 4 files with random names.** , One extra file with 0kb

[image]

Some more questions:

1. Can I do this conversion without creating a Glue table? What is the better way to handle this?
2. How to update modifications when a new file is added, When I rerun the job, it is regenerating all the files. I only need to update the modifications.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your data is rather small, you can also use a [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/?nc1=h_ls) which can do the same job, cheaper and quicker.
2. If you want to update the data (merge / upsert) you should look into using a  table format like [Delta Lake](https://%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format-delta-lake.html), which uses parquet as file format.

Comment: Thank you for reply! If I go with existing script, how to rename the files to match source file name as it generates random number now.

Comment: This would be a different question. Please close this one first and create a new. It would be appreciated if you could upvote / accept my answer, if it was helpful